# HTML5 canvas jQuery getContext on classes

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

**This code works:**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(0, 200);
      context.lineTo(578, 0);
      context.stroke();

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(0, 0);
      context.lineTo(578, 200);
      context.stroke();
    </script>
```

**I tried to do the same in jQuery and that did not work:**

"*Object [object Object] has no method 'getContext'*"

```
var context = $('.dropzone').getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 200);
context.lineTo(578, 0);
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(578, 200);
context.stroke();
```

**I even read on stackoverflow that I should try this (that did not work)**

Added a **[0]** to the code.

"*Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getContext'*"

```
var context = $('.dropzone')[0].getContext('2d');
```

**Question**

I want to "paint" in every .dropzone. Is that not possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.each()`

```
$('.dropzone').each(function(index, element) {
    var context = element.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 200);
    context.lineTo(578, 0);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(578, 200);
    context.stroke();   
});
```

Here's an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hx9GS/).

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using class in jquery.

Change this

`var context = $('.dropzone').getContext('2d');`

to

`var context = $('#dropzone').getContext('2d');`

Comment: I have unlimited multiple dropzones, can't use ID.

Comment: Then follow the rest of the answers using `each()` loop.

Comment: @JensTörnell that's the reason .getContext isn't working, perhaps someone could reformulate the answers to reflect this error?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `.each()` to iterate over all elements with that class.

```
$('.myCanvas').each(function() {
   var canvas = $(this)[0];
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // Do stuff
});
```

​
[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PdyXm/).