# html5 use canvas and script on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

First of all, i am a real newbie in html (in programming actually) and i'm french, so excuse my english.
Well, i am trying to build a website with multiple html pages, and i would like the background of ALL pages to be a noise generator :

```
function noise(ctx) {

    var w = ctx.canvas.width,
    h = ctx.canvas.height,
    idata = ctx.createImageData(w, h),               // create image data
    buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),   // get 32-bit buffer
    len = buffer32.length,
    i = 0;

    for(; i < len;)
        buffer32[i++] = ((255 * Math.random())|0) << 24; // alter alpha channel

    ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/dEya9/

I managed to make it work with an id element on the first page, but it won't display on any of the others. I know an id shouldn't be used multiple times, but i can't find a way to make this background work all the way.

Tell me if you need more precisions.
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084918/html5-canvas-jquery-getcontext-on-classes

Comment: Since you already have your `<canvas>` animation set up, you might want to convert it to a `gif` image, and then, both use this image as a general background, and save the loop calculation for each page. See http://codecartooning.tumblr.com/post/40840548952/converting-html5-canvas-animation-to-gif-animation

Comment: *"I know an id shouldn't be used multiple times"*, only on the same page.  You are misunderstanding that rule if you mean that you think you should only ever use the same element ID throughout the entire flow of your website.  Can you provide more insight on the structure of your site?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. I finally managed to make it work with the help of a friend who's actually programmation teacher. This was no id problem. We didn't find what mistakes i made, but we simply duplicated the first page several times and pasted content from the other pages inside the duplicata and it is now working perfectly well !

Answer (score 0):

`<body onload='noise(ctx)'>` on each page you would like this to run.  Make sure that the JS file is also linked within the header on that page, and that an element with the `id` exists.